# How to use HttpRequest and HttpResponse

Tags: php, httprequest, response

I have one question.

How can I use "HttpRequest::getResponseData()" to get a specific response out of a request?
If I sent a request with php to "google.com", then I get lot's of responses back. But I want to get only one specifical response.

What can I do to get that?

Greetings,
Dave

PS: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I need a way with PHP to get a specifical RESPONSE from a Request. I don't know how do I get this, so I found this "HttpRequest::getResponseData()" on the manual of PHP. How do I use this "Class"? Can somebody give me a small snippet please?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/httprequest.getresponsedata.php), this function only references the last response in the case of a series of redirects.

The fact that you are getting an array does not mean you have multiple responses. The array has a key for each header received. The body of the response has been given the key `body`

Comment: Can you bring an example snippet?

Comment: well, actually you need to show your snippet, and I can help you fix it.

Comment: I actually have no snippet, I did not know how to use this class.

Comment: then why are you using this class? why not just use `file()`, `file_get_contents()` or something similar?

Comment: Because I can't get a specifical Response out of it.

Comment: You need to be more clear. it is not clear what your question is